# Validate a jwt in angular?

Tags: angular, jwt

Morning;

I have a question about JWT and Angular.

I am looking to make all transactions between my front app (developed with angular) and my backend service using jwt to ensure data integrity.

So how can the angular App check and validate the jwt message? I know that app must use secret key to validate the jwt data but the problem where should I keep the secret key in angular app? Or I have to assume that the jwt is valid in all cases?

Cordially

Comment: The client (angular in this case) does not need to validate the jwt token. It simply stores and sends the jwt. The server will then verify that the jwt token is valid and respond appropriately.

Comment: but is not the token that I am talking about. What I want to acheive is to send data in jwt message format. for example : eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiSm9obiBEb2UiLCJkYXRhIjpbXX0.dprpNQZIhA-gu3sgduXDu5WD6OmbzmXrhQE0HoA4NfU

Comment: What do you mean by send data in jwt message format?

Comment: In a fact, What I mean is that claims in the jwt may be any data, product data, financial data, not only the predefined claims like sub, .. 
Maybe I should replace JWT by JWS to be more clear. So client must encode / decode the data with a secret key.

Comment: The header and payload (claims) are only base64UrlEncoded. They do not use the secret key. Only the signature is hashed with the secret key. Technically anyone who has your token can decode the header & payload

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact, my goal is to ensure data integity not to encrypt data. So, I have to use the access token as secret key?

Comment: From my understanding, only the server can ensure data integrity since it has the secret. Maybe [this](https://medium.facilelogin.com/jwt-jws-and-jwe-for-not-so-dummies-b63310d201a3) article will shed some light.

Answer (score 3):

The fact is your secret key is server-side. [Express JWT package](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt)
does a great job.

What you do client side is to check for it's validity.

You could use an Interceptor to check for integrity on each HTTP request: [Official docs on Interceptors](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)

Then on each request you would validate the JWT based on what you actually set server-side.
And then you handle your cases when the actual token is valid or invalid.

Here's a link to [Angular 2 JWT package](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt)

Comment: but I still need the secret key to validate the data sent by the server, even if I use Interceptors

Comment: That's what @LLai comment's is saying: "The client does not need to validate the JWT token" since it is checked against every HTTP requests

Comment: Sorry, I still can not understand. What do you mean by jwt token? it's not an access token?

Comment: What can't you understand ? (JWT stands for Javascript Web Token)

Comment: Thank you, I will look in the link that you provided me

Comment: Glad if it helped @AdouaniRiadh

Comment: @t3__rry Although my comment here is not relevant to the question asked, just wanted to clear that JWT stands for JSON Web Tokens and not JavaScript Web Token. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you are using the JWT. Normally, the signature is validated on the server when the JWT is sent back with each request (in a cookie or in the Authorization header).  This is to validate that the JWT has not been altered.  However, sometimes it is good to validate the integrity of the JWT in the client if the client needs to use claims in the JWT.

If the JWT was signed using a secret key, having it in the client puts the secret at risk of exposure - particularly when using a browser-based client such as Angular.  If the secret is compromised, it can then can be used to alter and sign a JWT with changes made.

If the JWT needs to be validated in the client, you should use a private/public key pair to sign and validate, respectively, the JWT.  Having the public key in the client to validate the JWT's signature does not pose a security risk. As it's name suggest, the public key is designed to be available to anyone.

The [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) package can also be used to handle the signed and verifying of JWTs.  A good website for help with JWT is [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: Just wanted to note for anyone landing on this page and answer that `jsonwebtoken` is a node-only package and cannot be used in browser to validate the JWT via public key, as it makes use of node-specific cryptographic APIs.

Comment: @Randolpho Just as a follow up, if anyone is looking for a library that works in both the back-end (say, node.js) and the front-end (say, angular), I found jose to work really well (I found it from the libraries section of jwt.io) and it seems to be quite self contained which is very nice: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose