# angular validate Jwt Token

Tags: angular, jwt

I have a public and private key to create a JWT token.
With the private key, I create a JWT token, and with the public key, I check the validity of the token.
To create a token on the server side, I use the following code:

```
        Jwts.builder()
          .setHeaderParam("typ","JWT")
          .claim("email", userPrincipal.getEmail())
          .claim("roles", roleList)
          .setIssuedAt(new Date())
          .setExpiration(new Date(new Date().getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
          .signWith(getPrivateKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.RS512)
          .compact();
```

To check the validity of the token on the server side, I use the public key and the following code:

```
        Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getPublicKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(jwtString);
```

Now my task is to check the validity of the token on the Angular client side.

Please tell me how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should check it on the client side!

Set your JWT token as an `HttpOnly` cookie so that future requests from the client side have the token as a cookie and you can evaluate the token on the server for each request.

Comment: I understand it. I need it on the client side.

Comment: Check this package https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken also this link can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324908/validate-a-jwt-in-angular

Comment: I tried to use it, but it doesn't work.
It's made for node.js
I installed it, but I can't import the package, it shows all sorts of errors.

Comment: The fact that you gave the link, I have seen, read and tried them all. This does not work.

Comment: Here is another link that may help you https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/ but I still think it's not a good thing to check that token on the client side and I don't know any package but the `jsonwebtoken` to check the validity of the token on the client side. Hope you find your answer and keep me updated, please. Good luck.

Comment: Keep these links for yourself. I myself can shower you with these links.